# A,B,X,Y are sets.. when is $X^Y \leq A^B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A,B,X,Y be sets with $X \leq A$ and $Y \leq B$. Prove that, apart from some exceptional cases, $X^Y \leq A^B$. What are the exceptional cases?

Comment: I presume $X \le A$ means there exists an injection $X \to A$.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the notation $S \le T$ here means that there is an injection $S \to T$. In which case, try to prove that if $X \le A$ and $Y \le B$ then $X^Y \le A^B$. You'll probably end up talking about *elements* of the sets in your proofs. Are there any sets where talking about their elements gets you into some trouble?